# Find how many times a pair of values occurs

Tags: matlab, montecarlo

Suppose there are 2 vectors `(i,j)`, `A(10,1)`, `B(10,1)` which have obtain random values from `[1,10]` interval. eg.

```
A = [1 6 1 10 1 7 1 9  3 6]
B = [7 2 3  5 6 8 7 9 10 2].
```

I am interested in creating a new vector which will count how many values with the same i index occur. e.g.

```
 1 and 7 ⇒ 2 occurrences
 6 and 2 ⇒ 2 occurrences
 1 and 3 ⇒ 1 occurrence
10 and 5 ⇒ 1 occurrence
 1 and 6 ⇒ 1 occurrence
...
```

etc.

So that a final array/vector `C` occurs, with all the possible pairs and their counted occurrence with size `C(number_of_pairs,2)`.

Comment: @LuisMendo: I *think* that's what the OP means... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
C = zeros(10);

for k = 1:10
    C(A(k), B(k)) = C(A(k), B(k)) + 1
end
```

Comment: Note that you get the same with `accumarray([A(:) B(:)], 1)`

Comment: Don't you need a `C = zeros (10,10)` for this to work?

Comment: @Kots `zeros(10)` is the same thing as `zeros(10,10)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and then [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
A = [1 6 1 10 1 7 1 9  3 6];
B = [7 2 3  5 6 8 7 9 10 2]; %// data

aa = accumarray([A(:) B(:)], 1); %// how many times each pair occurs
[ii jj vv] = find(aa);
C = [ii jj vv]; %// only pairs which occurr at least once
```

In your example, this gives

```
C =
     6     2     2
     1     3     1
    10     5     1
     1     6     1
     1     7     2
     7     8     1
     9     9     1
     3    10     1
```

Or perhaps `aa` or `vv` are what you need; I'm not sure about what your desired output is.

---

Another possible approach, inspired by [@Rody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21678075/2586922):

```
mat = [A(:) B(:)];
[bb ii jj] = unique(mat, 'rows');
C = [mat(ii,:) accumarray(jj,1)];
```

Comment: But beware that the peak memory footprint is O(N²) (as opposed to O(N) for the loopy solution)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I've added another approach, partly based on your answer, which may use less memory (depending on how `unique` internally works)

Comment: I timed all solutions here. Your first solution is fastest for both big and small `A` and `B`. My solution is **crap**. Dan's solution (with the `find` included) hovers somewhere in the middle :)

Comment: +1 but I'm not really sure you even need the `find`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
A = [1 6 1 10 1 7 1 9  3 6];
B = [7 2 3  5 6 8 7 9 10 2];

%// Find the unique pairs
AB  = [A;B].';
ABu = unique(AB, 'rows');

%// Count the number of occurrences of each unique pair
%// (pretty sure there's a better way to do this...)     
C = arrayfun(@(ii) ...
    [ABu(ii,:) sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, AB, ABu(ii,:)),2))], 1:size(ABu,1), ...
    'UniformOutput', false);
C = cat(1,C{:});
```

Result:

```
C =
     1     3     1
     1     6     1
     1     7     2
     3    10     1
     6     2     2
     7     8     1
     9     9     1
    10     5     1
```

Comment: @LuisMendo: No, probably a normal `for`-loop is faster. Oh well, your `accumarray` is way cooler anyway :)